# Is it allowed to consider "invalid" binomial coefficients as 0 (in a proof)?

Tags: solution-verification, summation, induction, binomial-coefficients

I want to prove (for the natural numbers) $$ \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}k = 2^n$$ by induction. In the induction step I want to apply this formula: $$\binom{n + 1}k = \binom{n}k + \binom{n}{k - 1}$$ This formula is for $k \geq 1$, but I will still apply it.

Induction step:

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} \binom{n + 1}k = \sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n}k + \sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n}{k - 1} $$

Now index shifting to receive the induction hypothesis:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n}k + \sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n}{k - 1} =\binom{n}{n+1}  +\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}k + \sum_{k=-1}^{n}\binom{n}k = \binom{n}{n+1}  +\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}k + \binom{n}{-1}+\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}k$$

According to the IH:
$$\binom{n}{n+1}  +\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}k + \binom{n}{-1}+\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}k = \binom{n}{n+1} + \binom{n}{-1} + 2^n + 2^n = \binom{n}{n+1} + \binom{n}{-1} + 2^{n+1}$$

$2^{n+1}$ matches the IH and would be a proof if $\binom{n}{n+1} + \binom{n}{-1}$ are $0$. I applied a rule I am actually not allowed to apply and this ends in probably invalid binomial coefficients. Since I am not able to select $n+1$ out of $n$ elements and $-1$ out of $n$
elements, they could maybe be considered as $0$ and the proof would be valid.

**Is it allowed to consider those binomial coefficients as 0?**

Comment: This is pretty standard. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Recursive_formula for a discussion on this.

Comment: @Gregory Thanks for your answer. So my proof would be valid, right?

Comment: A remark: $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}k = 2^n$ is a direct development of $(1+1)^n$. So unless you are requested to prove it by induction, it is not worth the effort.

Comment: It looks good to me, but I agree with the above comment.

Comment: It would also be good to be aware of what is called the Binomial series or Newton's Binomial theorem which is a generalization of the binomial theorem.

Comment: If $k<0$ or $k>n$, then $\binom{n}{k}:=0$. This is also convenient, since then $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\binom{n}{k}$, which e.g. makes index shifts (and, consequently, your proof) easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Alternatively, you could simply write
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}k$$
$$=\binom{n+1}0+\sum_{k=1}^n\left[\binom nk+\binom n{k-1}\right]+\binom{n+1}{k+1}$$
$$=1+\sum_{k=1}^n\binom nk+\sum_{k=1}^n\binom n{k-1}+1$$
$$=\binom n0+\sum_{k=1}^n\binom nk+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom nk+\binom nn$$
$$=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk+\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk$$
$$=2^n+2^n$$
$$=2^{n+1}.$$